# One count DAX for multiple columns that contains same values but in unorganised order, connected to rows

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

Hopefully I can make myself understood, we are doing a research on NPS (Customer satisfaction from 1 to 10 (1 sad and 10 happy) ). We use Quicksearch and have exported the raw data to PowerBI.

Every customer that has answered can choose up to 14 things they are satisfied/not satisfied with. I will name this A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N but in our report all the different letters are sentences, so: A = "Booking procedure" B = "Our prices" C = "Our website" and so on.

My goal is to get a record count of how many times each letter (sentences) has been mentioned (count) and thereafter I can filter away satisfied/not satisfied into different charts.

An example could look like this:

| NPS | Why satisfied/not satisfied |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | A, B, C |
| 5 | C, D, A, J |
| 1 | B, C, A, |
| 7 | N, A, K, J |
| 10 | H, I, N, A, B |
| 4 | K |
| 3 | A, B, C, D, E, F, K, L |
| 6 | K, L, D, E, A, B |

I've delimiter all the letters by comma, so now it is "Why satisfied/not satisfied" up to #6 (six columns).

| NPS | Why satisfied/not satisfied 1 | Why satisfied/not satisfied 2 | Why satisfied/not satisfied 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | A | B | C |
| 5 | C | D | A |
| 1 | B | C | A |
| 7 | N | A | K |

E.t.c.

And if i try to separate all the letters and put it in the same column, I will loose the possibility to filter out depending on what NPS (1-10) the customer choose. Because if they answer 10 in NPS and say "Our prices" they are satisfied and vice versa.

Each row (every answer) is over 30 cells long, so I can't lose that data that's why I somehow need to count/merge these "why satisfied..." columns so I can visualise it in example a bar chart.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Calculated Column` with the following DAX Formula without the need of splitting the columns

## DAX: Calculated Column

```
Count Responses = 
    PATHLENGTH(
        SUBSTITUTE([Why satisfied/not satisfied],",","|")
    )
```

## Output

[image]

---

## Edit

I have created a table containing all the letters of the alphabet with this DAX Code

```
Letters = 
ADDCOLUMNS ( GENERATESERIES ( 1, 26, 1 ), "Letter", UNICHAR ( [Value] + 64 ) )
```

It creates this table

[image]

With that table created, I create the following measure

## DAX Measure

```
CountLetters =
VAR SelectedLetter =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Letters[Letter] )
VAR t1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        'Table',
        "LetterBoolean", CONTAINSSTRING ( [Why satisfied/not satisfied], SelectedLetter )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( T1, [LetterBoolean] = TRUE ) )
```

## Output

Using the `Letter` column from the `Letters` table and `CountLetters` measure the output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply! 

It was not an easy task to formulate this problem, but I need to calculate all the A's seperate, B's and C's etc. 

So in my example there is 7 A's, 5 B's and etc.

Comment: Hey @Fraita, I've modified the answer. If you find it helpful please label the answer as the solution.